# Request for rscala tag?

Tags: feature-request, tags

I have just started using rscala. It's a slick interface between R and Scala. Might I suggest a tag for this Scala utility?

Although rscala is relatively new and undocumented, it seems to be getting a following, is under regular development, and meets an increasingly common demand for big data analysts.

Comment: Please can you list some existing questions that you'd tag with this tag.

Comment: consider writing the excerpt and wiki: https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/03/24/redesigned-tags-page/

Comment: see here: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=rscala